# Getting stack trace from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have a C# program on Visual Studio 2012 that has an error. How can I retrieve the stack trace?

Comment: You mean in the UI?  Debug, Window, Stack Trace.   But you have to have an exception first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While debugging, the stacktrace is accessible as the "Call Stack" window. If you want the stacktrace of an exception you caught, it is accessible through the [`StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) member of the Exception you caught:

```cs
try
{
    [...]
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Write(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

To add another useful example:

```cs
try
{
    [...]
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

This will print to the Visual Studio debug console instead of the console window of your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an Exception, you can get a [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by calling the member of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This is some code I use to get details

```
if (e.Exception.InnerException != null)
{
    sb.AppendLine("InnerException");
    if (e.Exception.InnerException.Message == null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.InnerException.Message == null");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.InnerException.Message = " + e.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace))
    {
        sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace ");
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string line in e.Exception.InnerException.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
            count++;
            if (count > 10) break;
        }
    }
}
sb.AppendLine("OuterException");
if (e.Exception.Message == null)
{
    sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.Message == null");
}
else
{
    sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.Message = " + e.Exception.Message);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Exception.StackTrace))
{
    sb.AppendLine("e.Exception.StackTrace ");
    int count = 0;
    foreach (string line in e.Exception.StackTrace.Split('\n'))
    {
        sb.AppendLine(line.Trim());
        count++;
        if (count > 10) break;
    }
}
```